# DBT Command not working from inside a container in a k8s pod

Tags: amazon-eks, dbt

dbt command exits silently from within the pod despite having the .dbt folder and profiles.yml

dbt debug
dbt test

The above command works from my local set up but doesnt work from within the pod and connects to Snowflake.
I have verified the Firewall connection and we dont have anything blocking from the source.